Identifying connector & plug
What is this connector and plug? Googled, went through molex catalog, could not find.  Any ideas?


Please show a close-up of the connector, a few angles of the plug wouldn't be a bad idea, and a measurement of the pin pitch.

Soo, after googling more - it is Molex Pico Spox series stuff.
Now - how can I crimp it “for cheap”, as official tool is 500eur 
